# How to use custom object methods with Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have several custom js objects, where I encapsulated needle logic.
So, these objects don't have relation with vuex at all, something like that:

```
export default class Property {
   constructor(object) {
      // some logic
   }
   addChild(property) {
      // some logic
   }
}
```

Also, I have button in my vue component, which firing vue method:

```
methods: {
    addItem() {
        this.property.addChild();
    },
},
```

And there is problem:
`this.property` - it is object from vuex store.
So, when I call method in such way, I get vue error:

```
Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

Yeah, I understand, what Vue wants.
But for me it is more clear to encapsulate some complex logic in needle objects. Also, I want to use vuex for global app state.

So, please, could you share experience how to deal with vuex and custom object methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vuex you simply have to use mutation to alter it's states.
So, in the the Property object's `addChild` function, 
where you would alter state, I assume you would do it like

```
Store.state.xxx = 'new'
```

Instead of doing that, you call mutation like

```
Store.commit('alterState')
```

There's not too much difference in terms of complexity, right?